# Настройки Hibernate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hibernate

Есть файл конфигурации hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Idea ругается на строку

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
```

"org.h2.driver is not assignable to java.sql.driver".   В чем может быть причина?  Гугль не помог ((

Зависимости pom.xml

```
<groupId>pro.tariel</groupId>
<artifactId>auth</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>auth</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pom.xml` покажите ваш

Comment: У вас не задан connection url, укажите его: `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:путь</property>`

Comment: Путь задавал. На драйвер никак не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Решено.  Удалил проект, создал новый с теми же настройками, все заработало. Видимо, какой-то локальный глюк, поэтому и загуглить не удалось.